# React Load Spinner While Array of Images Load

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, visual-web-developer

I have an array of img src tags I'm dynamically setting when I pass the itemName as shown in and then rendering the full array. I want to show a Spinner until all the images are done loading however the current behavior is during a refresh or initial load, some layers load before the others taking some time to all fully load and no Spinner is showing.

I'd like to show the full array of images as once, not have some layers show and watch the loading process. I am not making any API calls, just finding the path of the images located in my project structure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class BodyOption extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {    

        let option = null; // initial state
        var wantedOption = this.props.itemName;
        var optionCategory = this.props.optionCategory;
        optionCategory = optionCategory.replace(/ /g, "");
    
        var fileName = optionCategory+"_"+wantedOption+".png";

        try {

            option =  
                <div key={optionCategory} className={classes.Layer}>
                   <img src {require(`../../../assets/images/${optionCategory}/${fileName}`).default} alt={wantedOption}/>   
                 </div>
         } catch (err) {
            option = null
         }  

         return option;
    }
};
export default BodyOption;
```

```
import Spinner from '../UI/Spinner/Spinner';
import ClassicBodyOption from './ClassicOptions/ClassicBodyOption';
const classes = require('./Classic.module.css');

class Classic extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() { 
        let  var transformedClassicBodyOptions = Object.keys(this.props.classicBodyOptions)
        .map(igKey => {
            return Object.keys(this.props.classicBodyOptions[igKey] ).map(realKey => {   
                return [...Array((this.props.classicBodyOptions[igKey][realKey] ))].map( 
                    (itemName, i) =>  {
                        const keyName = realKey.replace(/ /g, "");
                        return <BodyOption 
                            key={keyName + i} 
                            optionCategory={realKey}
                            itemName={itemName}
                           />;
                    });       
            });
        })
        .reduce((prevVal, currVal) => { // this just flattens array
            return prevVal.concat(currVal); 
        }, [  ]);

            return (

                    <div className={classes.Classic}>
                        {transformedClassicBodyOptions}
                    </div>
            );
    }  
}
export default Classic;
```

Comment: *it's not working* - please explain what this means... "not working" can be anything.

Comment: Also [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: For this you want a different approach than a loading spinner, you're not asynchronously making a request to get the image, that request is effectively happening on page load. What is the current behaviour, it takes a while for the image to 'paint' on the screen?

Comment: @BrianThompson  Sorry I'll change it. When refreshing the page, I'd like the whole array of images to load at once (they are stacked images on top of each other) but they kind of trickle in. It's not working as in no Spinner is showing, I'm assuming since transformedBodyOptions is called before the check and always not null.

Comment: @BrettEast Some layers of the images show before the others as they do take some time to all load fully. What kind of approach would be best? Is a Spinner not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Condition to check state and show content based on the state.
Just have to set this.state.doneLoading when you have all your pictures.

```
render() {
    return <div>
    { this.state.doneLoading
        ? <ImagesComponent/>
        : <LoadingSpinnerComponent/>
    }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out when to set the doneLoading state since I'm I have an array of images being called on the pageLoad, not in something like an apiCall

Comment: Do you know the expected number of images base on the props given? Or are you loading them from somewhere? If you know, you could set you condition to if images.length === expected_length

Comment: Yeah I've tried this but still see no Spinner                                                                             return (
                    <div className={classes.Classic}>
                        {this.state.pictureArray.length == 68 ? this.state.pictureArray : <Spinner/>}
                    </div>
            );